# Algorithm for map<int,vector<int> >

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I'm having trouble of thinking up an efficient algorithm for a map vector issue I have.

Say I have a map<int , vector <int> > and i would like to find out how many times an integer occurs in all of vector of the map, and if it occurs over a predefined amount remove it's value from the rest of vectors (hopefully that makes sense), here is a quick example:

---

**key                values**

1  - <2,3,4,4,5>

2 - <2,3,3,4,5>

3- <2,3,3,4,6>

In this case say I wanted to remove 4 from all the vector if it has occurred more than three times. The resulting map would look like this:

1  - <2,3,4,4,5>

2 - <2,3,3,4,5>

3- <2,3,3,DEL,6>

---

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm for this issue and was just wondering if anyone had any ideas. (I'm working in C++ , but I know java or pseudo code is cool).

Thanks for any help

Side Note the vectors are not sorted in real life just in this example.

Comment: Assuming you don't have a reverse-map (integer to key), I think your only option is to go through one-by-one from the beginning to end...

Comment: @lc I was thinking that myself, but if he needs to remove more than one number (e.g. 4 and 6 and 8), wouldn't it be more efficient to build a separate data structure first, then remove all of them?

Comment: Why not use `std::multimap<int, int>`?

Comment: Thats exactly what i was thinking of doing constructing the reverse map and then using a count in that one to perform the deletion in the main map. Iterating over the whole map would give me something along the lines of O(n)^n not cool.

Comment: You can build a map of integers and counts. After the required hit is enumerated on the given integer just remove all the rest as you go trough the whole structure one by one.

Comment: is that map of vectors a requirement? if so, the naive algorithm is the most efficient... if not, you should ask for a good data structure, and not force your current implementation. `^` ??

Comment: In your example, the vectors are sorted. Is that a rule?

Comment: @vlad Yes, I suppose that's a question for Nark: Is the count-and-remove operation only going to be done once or do you have to remove more than one number?

Comment: @vlad  I have to remove more than one number (cheers lc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the vectors aren't sorted the only way to do this is to iterate through all the items of all the vectors, keep track of how many have been found, and clean up the vector as appropriate. I think it would be straightforward to do this with an externally stateful predicate and the remove-erase idiom.

Given your precise needs and container use however, alternate approaches might be available. For example if the `vector` doesn't actually need to be indexable you could use a `multiset` instead to keep the items sorted and provide easy counting and removal.

Comment: MultiSet's were a great suggestion to be honest I had forgotten about them and my structure requirements didn't actually require me to have an index (at this point in time). Thanks for your help everyone.